# Python building multiple arg parameters

Tags: python

I want to convert certain values of a dictionary as multiple args and pass it to a method. The key of the dict needs to be the name of the variable passed to the method.

eg:

```
myDict={'one':1,'two':2,'three':3,'four':4}

#call myMethod as
myMethod(one=1,two=2)

def myMeth(self,*args):
     do somthing with args
```

Comment: You can create a method which take list of list. I think it will do your task. like - myMethod([['one',1],['two',2]])

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unpacking notation.  If you have a method like this

```
def function(arg1,arg2,arg3):
    # do something
```

and a dictionary `dct = {'arg1':3,'arg2':3,'arg3':6}`, you can call the function like

```
function(**dct)
```

which is equivalent to doing `function(arg1=3,arg2=3,arg3=6)`.

Notice the double stars.  This means to take the dictionary and pass its values as named parameters where the keys are the names.  A single star would unpack a list, passing its values in order as unnamed parameters.  These can be combined.

See section [4.7.4](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) of the python documentation for more detail.  [Here](http://hangar.runway7.net/python/packing-unpacking-arguments) is another article discussing these as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `**` for passing or accepting dictionary arguments. The following code

```
d={'foo': 'bar','test': 123}

def my_method(**kwargs):
    print kwargs

my_method(**d)
```

would print the contents of `d`, `{'foo': 'bar','test': 123}`

EDIT: @Matthew 's answer sums it up nicely, via the comparison of `*args`.